How to Retrieve Salesforce Access Token from Cognito after Federated Login
I have set up AWS Cognito to use Salesforce as an external identity provider (IDP) for user login in my application. The current flow is as follows:
The user is redirected to Cognito's default login UI, where they can choose Salesforce as the login option.

Upon selecting Salesforce, Cognito sends the authentication request to Salesforce.

After the user logs into Salesforce, Salesforce sends an authorization code back to Cognito.

Cognito exchanges this code for a token and then redirects the user back to my application with a Cognito code.

I exchange this Cognito code to receive a JWT from Cognito.

Now, I need to make API calls to Salesforce from my application using the token that Cognito receives from Salesforce. However, I am unsure how to retrieve the Salesforce token (access token or refresh token) from Cognito.
I have even tried setting up a Pre token generation Lambda trigger but iam unable to get the salesforce access_token or referesh_token
My Question: How can I extract the Salesforce access token (or refresh token) from Cognito after the federated login?
Any help or guidance would be appreciated. Thank you!

Token Exchange: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_token_exchange_use_cases.htm&type=5

In the scenario you described, you won't be able to get the Salesforce token.  The Salesforce token is being exchanged/used between Cognito and Salesforce during that login process, and what Cognito ultimately provides back to the original caller is a Cognito token, as you have stated.  There are two tokens in the interaction:

a token which Cognito obtains when it completes the login loop with Salesforce, and it uses this token to get details about the logged-in user so it can map that user to a Cognito user.  Cognito does not make this accessible to the original caller.
a token which Cognito provides back to the original caller.  This is not a Salesforce token at all, and all of your subsequent client usage of this 2nd token are going against Cognito.

If you need to be able to provide a Saleforce token, perhaps the question is why are you using Cognito at all?  Why not do the SSO directly with Salesforce instead so that you have that token?  Essentially, Cognito is a middle-man at that point, and if you don't need Cognito for anything else other than to facilitate the login, then it may be better to eliminate it from the architecture and go directly to Salesforce.

Thank you for your suggestion! My application is already using Cognito for login and user management. so, i have though to integrate salesforce with cognito for centralized user management

Well, you can still integrate for centralized user management, and you can get user details from Salesforce and have them be essentially replicated to Cognito so you can access them via your Cognito token (via mappings).  But you won't be able to use that token to call Salesforce APIs directly.

Then is there any other way that we can call Salesforce API while integrating with congnito.

This video shows how to do it from the Salesforce side--kind of a reverse of what you described: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eBfGAHCFHD8
